# Вопрос о работе программиста

Tags: работа

Здравствуйте!
Вот мне на протяжении всего времени, что занимаюсь программированием, мне было интересно, где могут работать программисты, например, старше 50 лет? Ведь технологии и языки программирования развиваются, одно заменяется другим, что-то вообще становится лишним, и его постепенно забывают. А в пожилом возрасте уже не до изучения нового, да и жизненные обстоятельства не всегда позволяют...
Можно основать свою компанию и потом передать дело в руки других, при этом деньги сами будут течь к вам в руки, но это редкость. Так вот, какие у вас планы на свое дальнейшее будущее?

Comment: программисты не всю жизнь программируют, и есть *должности* программистов(которые можно занять по получении опыта), не требующие в дальнейшем программирования как такового.

Comment: А чего Вы такого плохого мнения о людях после 50? У некоторых мозги работают на порядок лучше молодых. Я вот хотя еще не старик, но уже далеко не юноша, но с каждым годом соображаю все лучше и новое осваиваю быстрее.

Comment: @mikillskegg, я ничего не имею против пожилых людей, а даже наоборот.
Мне просто интересно узнать, какие перспективы на будущее ставят себе программисты.

Comment: Есть где-то изследования даже, публиковали. Деградация мышления происходит не от возраста а от отсутствия самого мышления. Естественно, могут помешать болезни. Но опыт показывает ,что кто думает, тот думает всю жизнь.

Comment: Не знаю, но по себе скажу, что после 30-35 голова работает медленнее.

Comment: @mikillskegg "но с каждым годом соображаю все лучше и новое осваиваю быстрее" -- есть результаты объективных исследований? @avp медленнее -- это как? Становится лениво делать массу ошибок?

Comment: @alexlz, лениво, это тоже. 

Но я имел в виду немного другое. Раньше я как-то сразу видел все (ну, многие) последствия некого архитектурного решения, а теперь это осознание все чаще приходит по ходу проектирования (кодирования). 

С ужасом (конечно это шутка) думаю, что скоро буду видеть это только в процессе завершающего тестирования.

Comment: @avp Вы потихоньку становитесь нормальным?

Comment: Ну, как я понимаю, то по большому счету, люди продолжают вполне нормально работать программистами и после 50 лет...

Comment: Настоящему программисту в гроб кладут мышку и клавиатуру.

Comment: Нельзя все свое время посвящать коддингу. Программирование должно занимать в жизни 3-4 позицию, иначе человек перестанет быть собой...

Comment: А вот интересно, что у Вас занимает в жизни места до программирования?

Comment: Элементарные человеческие ценности. Я не говорю о материальных ценностях. Вы понимаете, что я имею ввиду. Если в жизни человека 1 место - программирование, тогда ему неведомы все остальные прелести жизни =)

Comment: @Asen, а кто-то с этим спорит ? Вообще хорошо, когда у человека **несколько** увлечений (хобби) и совсем хорошо когда источники существования и хобби совпадают.

Comment: Первое место вовсе не означает, что для человека ничего другого не существует. Но я убежден (в том числе и на собственном опыте), что если кто-то хочет достичь в каком-то деле настоящих высот, то это дело для него должно стать первым (хотя, конечно, необязательно единственным). Само собой, разные моральные ограничения и все такое.

Comment: @mikillskegg А что у Вас получается в результате прохождения теста на нердность? "О, великий Отец Hердов, девственные логарифмические линейки я жертвую тебе!"?

Comment: чем старше, тем человек способен на то, что в молодости у него заняло бы уйму времени...
Как была у меня беседа год назад, с одним преподавателем в университе. Человеку около 50-55 лет. Преподает интегральные и вариационные исчисления. Ассемблер изучил за 1 неделю...
Сейчас паяет микросхемы и активно использует сиё на практике.

Comment: @Александр Маслов, "изучил" понятие растяжимое. Синтаксис изучить не составит труда. А вот написать что-то толковое и есть ли в этом смысл, это совершенно другой вопрос.

Comment: Это нескромно, но факт: все, кто моложе меня в нашей фирме даже не знают в сторону каких новых технологий нужно смотреть.

Comment: @Softa оно, конечно, не по теме данного вопроса, но поделитесь, на какие технологии сейчас нужно смотреть. Please!

Comment: Мне, кстати, кажется, что жизнь была бы намного лучше, если вместо новых технологий все смотрели бы в сторону, например, Кормена.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, логика уровня "хочу быть программистом, чтобы в 50 жить на Канарах" не предполагает чтения книжек :)

Comment: @Котик, а второй Кормен (который, режиссер) может для этих целей тоже сгодится?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Мой батя (1951 г.р.) в восьмидесятых годах работал в институте кибернетики, когда [перфокарта](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0) была высокотехнологическим гаджетом  ;) Так вот сейчас, когда ему уже без месяца 61 год, он плавает во всех новшествах, как рыба в воде. Дело, я так думаю, что не в возрасте. Сейчас это модно, а в то время, люди шли, как говориться, по призванию. И если ты в этом направлении себя нашел, то уже будешь до конца дней своих кодить))

Comment: хочу добавить, что кодить будешь только в своё удовольствие

Comment: Да, но древние технологии( перфокарта, на которую вы указали ), наверное, оставили глубокий след в понимании работы кода и всем с этим связанным...

Comment: вот именно! все современные языки программирования и фреймворки очень многое скрывают от программистов, поэтому это многое практически никто и не знает, а программисты тех лет понимают как программы располагаются в памяти, как процессор исполняет код, как создаются и уничтожаются процессы и потоки, это ОГРОМНЫЙ плюс!

Comment: @Deonis раньше лениво было комментировать, но спасибо @Softa... С каких пор перфокарта стала гаджетом, и сколько этой самой перфокарте лет? (Из прошлого: перфокарта -- ерунда, а вот перфокарта с краевой надпечаткой -- это да!)

Answer (score 12):

В компании, где я работаю (очень известная международная компания), есть много людей старше 50. И среди программистов в том числе. Хотя у нас используют много новых технологий. Они же всю жизнь развиваются, и поэтому привыкают к постоянному изучению нового, думаю. Есть еще часть людей, кто перешел в технические писатели или в тестировщики. Есть и старше 60 :) У нас иерархия совсем небольшая, т.е. нет огромного количества начальников. Team lead занимается и программированием, и управлением (и они обычно молодые). А над ним только совладельцы. Но есть много компаний (чаще всего крупных, от 1.000, от 10.000, и т.д. человек), где начальников разных уровней много, где и могут найти себя люди старше 50.

Comment: Спасибо, я, если честно, раньше думал, что большинство программистов пожилого возраста идут работать учителями в школы и институты, так как это менее напряженная работа, за компьютером приходится сидеть менее, чем среднему программисту...

Comment: Вы думаете, у школьная учителя ненапряженная работа?

Comment: один мой бывший препод, которому под 60 уже, занимается небольшими заказами, у него даже были клиенты из Германии и Австрии, из Израиля, хоть проподаёт он не очень, но своё дело знает!

Comment: @mikillskegg, нет, я так не думаю. Я думаю, что у школьного учителя работа менее напряженная, ЧЕМ у программиста =)

Comment: Очень в этом сомневаюсь. В школу я бы пошел работать только в самом крайнем случае.

Comment: Уважаемый @Spectre, "...уже под 60...",- да он пацан, фактически. В 64 года меня еще брали и взяли в программисты, и было мне счастье, пока "судьба не постучалась в дверь". Дальше тишина, почти.

Comment: Уважаемый @mikillskegg,"Вы думаете, у школьная учителя ненапряженная работа?", - "Велик могучим русский языка!"

Comment: @BuilderC, и что?

Comment: @mikillskegg Опять берём и читаем аргументы Дейкстры об общей грамотности программистов. Статьи его в открытом доступе (большинство правда в растре). Голландец был довольно известным программистом (размещение переменных в стеке для языков с блоками -- его идея).

Comment: @alexlz, детский сад какой-то. При чем тут грамотность? Просто описка. Очень хочется над кем-то постебаться? Постебался? Доволен?

Answer (score 10):

Мне уже скоро полтинник стукнет и ничего работаю. Начинал с перфокарт, с огромных EC-1061/1035, потом пересел на PDP/СМ-1420, в свое время работал даже с Cray'ами. В первый раз коснулся инета, когда многие из вас еще под стол пешком ходил - в 1993 году (в стране тогда был один единственный сайт на Курчатовском). Ну в общем чего рассказывать - все было.

Конечно уже мало кодирую - так больше для души или чтобы учить молодежь. В основном рулю проектами + внедрение + развитие.

По моим наблюдениям: критический возраст девелопера начинается где-то в районе сороковника. Если к 40-ка ты не стал хотя бы team-lead, то можно уже сливать воду. Конечно, есть туча исключений приведенных народом здесь, но это лишь исключения. Реальность увы такова, что после соракета уже трудно найти работу девелопером (но не невозможно). Все зависит не столько от квалификации (квалификация к этому времени по любому уже есть), сколько от настроя на работу, способности к самообучению.

Так что мой вам совет, дорогие мои молодые девелоперы: учитесь всю жизнь - это не зазорно. Ну и про карьеру не забывайте - тут важно ведь не столько уметь уметь управлять потоками байтов/битов, а и людьми. Управлять людьми малька посложнее будет.

Comment: Стареют Бармалеи. Хотя до BuilderC ещё расти и расти.

Comment: Ага, особенно учитывая, что билдер уже слег совместно с Борландом

Comment: Бармалей бессмертен!

Comment: @Barmaley, а Cray родной (из под эмбарго) или Электроника СС-БИС ?

Comment: @avp родной Cray Кеплеровский университет Линца

Answer (score 9):

Последний год я работал с одной дамой в возрасте, скажем, за 50. Она в свое время много работала в каких-то определенных фирмах, в резюме четко прослеживается смена одних языков другими. В данный момент большей частью работает по договорам, на отдельных проектах, подрабатывает где придется, как и многие здесь.

Что для меня оказалось удивительным, она совершенно не знала сетей. Наш проект, неотрывно связанный с сетями, тем не менее руководитель ее взял. Мне пришлось некоторое время потратить, чтобы ей кое-что пояснить, многое объяснять было сложно, а некоторое так и осталось "за кадром". Но говорить о том, что она сидит без дела или не знает программирования совершенно нельзя. Опыта много, оптимизационные задачи щелкает как семечки, есть и идеи, и конкретные реализации. Постоянно чем-то занята, составлен четкий график, без этого, к сожалению, здесь не выкарабкаться, очень много времени уходит на перезды между городами, работаем в одном, учимся в другом, живем в третьем.

Несмотря на все это скорость обучения, да и вообще работы, у нее несколько меньше, нежели у более молодых, зато работает она целенаправленно, с меньшей "погрешностью", если так можно выразиться. А поэтому время на более долгое обучение компенсируется.

Говорить о способностях людей нужно субъективно, рассматривая каждого в отдельности. К тому же, я не верю, что толковый программист не видит явного изменения интереса к языкам, которые он изучал ранее. А соответственно, сделав некоторые выводы, мы и прийдем к тому, что нужно искать/изучать что-то новое. Да и о себе судить сложно, кто его знает, что будет в будущем, вдруг через пару месяцев концепции и парадигмы программирования рухнут?

Comment: Согласен. Заметил то же самое - программисты в возрасте, благодаря опыту, сразу смотрят далеко и закладывают в свои программы возможности развития, расширения, доделки. А молодняк пишет лишь бы работало, не понимая к каким косякам это приведет через полгода, когда ему же придется модернизировать эту ахинею. Хотя при этом молодняк более склонен к изучению новых технологий, но это изучение оно как бы бессмысленно - недавно пришлось с нуля переписывать довольно много кода, в который архитектор его - начинающий программист - умудрился встроить пять плохо совместимых между собой технологий.

Answer (score 6):

Программирование - это, как искусство. Либо способен, либо нет =)

Answer (score 5):

> Так вот, какие у вас планы на свое
> дальнейшее будущее?

Ну я планирую к полтосу лет - загорать на канарах, в то время когда моя корпорация будет вносить свою лепту в экономику самой корпорации, так же заниматься постоянной благотворительностью и сотрудничать с государственными структурами с целью развития самого государства!

Все выше написаное конечно утрирование... Честно говоря я не задумываюсь что и как и кем и т.д. я буду через еще 24 года! Это фактически половина моей жизни, и к тому же, 6 лет назад я даже и не думал что буду программистом, по этому как можно размышлять на прдмет планов?

З.Ы. Среднестатистическая продолжительность мужчин в наше время 48 лет! Так что дай бог дожить...

Comment: Хех))) А почему бы не задуматься над первым абзацем всерьёз???

Вы пишете:
>    Среднестатистическая продолжительность мужчин в наше время 48 
>    лет

**Программисты, полностью погруженные в свое дело, живут еще меньше**

Comment: Как раз наоборот: человек, активно занимающийся любимым делом, постоянно работающий мозгом, имеющий интерес к жизни и к новому, непрерывно развивающийся, живет дольше других. Это факт.

Comment: какая-то идеальная вселенная получилась у вас, мы живём немного в другой

Comment: Видимо, тут стереотипы схлестнулись) 

Есть прогеры, которые развиваются только в плане программирования (гики/задроты/фанатики, как хотите), они - меньше.

Есть такие, кто развивается в общем (программирование в т.ч.), но не отказываются ради этого от отпусков, походов в горы, пикников и т.п., они - дольше) Все просто)

То что уровень знаний немного разный, об этом я промолчу. Но с некоторых пор мне больше нравится второе.

Comment: @Sh4dow крут коммент)

Comment: Скажу что, дай бог чтобы было всем и каждому... Уже никогда не будет тех времен равным 60-90 годам и тут посталю три жирные(простите выражусь на своем языке) крапки!

Comment: @Sh4dow если более точно ответить по поводу схлестывания стереотипов то:
есть программисты старающиеся вести здоровый образ жизни(не бухают, не курят, соблюдают режим сна, ведут активный отдых и т.д.), а есть программисты кторым на это начхать. Так что примеры ни о чем не скажут, все зависит от самого человека.

Comment: @Palmervan, сразу видно, что еще совсем молодой. В одну кучу - 60-е, 90-е... Совершенно разные эпохи, с разными проблемами и достоинствами.

Comment: Да, @Sh4dow, плюсую ваш коммент =)

Comment: 48 лет - это не для программистов. А для сильно пьющих людей без специальности.

Answer (score 4):

Может это и смешно (наивно), но приведу небольшой житейский пример: я периодически хожу к отцу моего знакомого (отцу за 60 лет) "перебивать винду". Данный "father"  до пенсии работал инженером по электрооборудованию (примерно так). Вот, короче, на старости лет он начал делать какие-то инженерные расчеты :), причем изучил использование формул в MS Excel (у нас в институте 90 % этого не могли). Во время очередного посещения я увидел у него книгу по Pascal и соответственно предложил перейти на Delphi 7 (С++ не стал предлагать). И что вы думаете, прихожу через пару-тройку месяцев, а у него прога "шустрит" по Access`у (можно простить :)) и еще спрашивает: "может мне разделить функционал между клиентом и COM-сервером DLL"! Отсюда делаю вывод: если есть желание и мозги - то нет никаких проблем. А по-поводу развития технологий, то действительно, данной категории людей труднее схватывать новшества, но зато они методичны и упорны в достижении поставленной цели!

Comment: А вот насчёт delphi/c++ -- так старость надо уважать, а не подсовывать такие инструменты. Подозреваю, что в данном случае питон был бы значительно лучше.

Comment: Может, С++ и было бы слишком сурово, но Дельфи - не такой уж и сложный инструмент программирования.

Comment: Хоть сейчас многие и говорят, что Delphi постепенно умирает( и я в какой-то степени с этим согласен... ), но я лично не особо хотел бы расставаться с этой средой, не смотря на то, что C# и Python не так уж оторвались от дельфи. Delphi почти ежегодно обновляется, в нем можно сделать почти все, начиная от сортировки массива и заканчивая COM-сервером или веб-сервером, например.

Comment: @Asen "отцу за 60 лет", "я лично не особо хотел бы расставаться ... COM-сервером или веб-сервером" -- почувствуйте разницу. Ну и не по теме, что касается COM'ов, питоновцы (кажись Hammond) утверждают, что питон -- лучший для com'ов инструмент -- в c++ (думаю, delphi туда же) нелегко работать с наследниками IDispatch, VB не годится для наследников IUnknown.

Comment: То, что Дельфи не так популярны как раньше, не говорит о том, что он умирает. А говорит только о том, что постоянное появляются другие технологии. Наличие более-менее доведенного, наконец-то, до ума Лазаруса о многом говорит. Да и платная версия Дельфи развивается.

Answer (score 3):

ИМХО В 50 лет не солидно быть рядовым программистом, надо быть минимум Тим Лидом, а лучше Менеджером Проекта с большой заработной платой. Люди в 50 лет (программисты) получают по 10к зелени в крупных ИТ компаниях и в подчинении имеют около 100 молодых программистов. Так , что всегда есть к чему стремиться.

Comment: А тех 50-летних, которые не стали Тим Лидами (не не хватило им тимов), куда -- в дворники, или в ближайшем пруду топить?

Comment: Зачем же сразу топить в пруду?? )))

Comment: Действительно интересно, если не получилось тим лидом, а мозги уже не варят к 40, то что делать? Так и получать 1к$? А там ведь дети в университет пойдут... У меня в планах накопить капитал да открыть некоторое свое дельце, которым могут стать пару сайтиков, приносящих "несложную" прибыль. А может это "дельце" будет вовсе не из области ИТ)) Сидеть перед монитором всю жизнь - так себе перспективка...

Comment: Бред полный. Все не могут быть тим-лидами. И по своим внутренним психологическим данным и по количеству мест свободных для тим-лидов.

Answer (score 3):

Так, подведу итог: надо стать как минимум тим лидом, желательно оторваться от написания кода, научиться управлять командой. Главное уметь обучаться на протяжении всей жизни, не терять настрой. Ум не стареет. Можно найти альтернативную работу.
Как насчет пенсий? Думаю, есть пару вариантов:

1. работать "до гроба" хD
2. Создать свою компанию
3. Подсобирать денег, скажем так 1-mln-USD, или продать комп нафиг xD
4. Сделать бизнес в альтернативной сфере (а что, мы программеры, люди разносторонние))))
5. Найти работу с пенсией
6. Выростить заботливых детей и просто жить
7. Совместить несколько предыдущих вариантов

В общем возраст для прогера - это экзамен всей его деятельности. Удачи!

Comment: @semenvx27, aaa, вот уж повеселил 3-ий пункт!))

Answer (score 2):

50 лет - не предел для "творчества" ?

Если в кавычках, то не предел. Реально же все действительно крупные открытия (изобретения) были сделаны людьми в возрасте до 35 лет.

Comment: Спасибо и вам)

Comment: Три раза ХА. Внимательно посмотрите историю науки. 

Вы путаете с другим - если к "возрасту Иисуса" ничего не достиг, то и не достигнешь. Но это не означает, что все достижения в этом возрасте и прекращаются.

Comment: @Softa, Вы не путаете момент, когда человек *реально делает открытие* с дальнейшей деятельностью по "донесению" его до "ученого сообщества"?

Что бы не быть голословным приведу первые вспомнившиеся имена:


Ньютон (IMHO гений №1 всех времен, ну, оптикой заинтересовался уже в зрелые годы), Эйнштейн, Менделеев (как раз на грани 35-ти)....

Если посмотреть на IT, то Крэю было 35, когда запустили CDC 1604, а о возрасте  плеяды истинных хакеров из MIT (думаю о том, что они делали говорить не надо) я вообще молчу.

Исключения, безусловно, есть (как известно, подтверждает правило).

Answer (score 1):

У меня препод в универе до пенсии работал! ооп преподавал и успешно!

Comment: Кстати да, преподавание/наука/несложные "проектики" вполне приемлимый вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в Google Play Market проги на android делать...

Comment: Бугагашенька :)))

Comment: А че. Один из самый успешных российский андроидоделов - человек в возрасте под 50. Читайте Хабр. У него там много интересных статей.

Comment: Можно, конечно, то-то там столько дерьма всякого.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько месяцев назад появилось [небольшое исследование](http://people.engr.ncsu.edu/ermurph3/papers/msr13.pdf) Моррисона и Мёрфи-Хилла, в котором изучалась связь возраста и деятельности на StackOverflow, использованной как представление знаний программиста. Очень советую его прочитать, но кратко основные результаты были таковы:

- возраст положительно коррелирует с репутацией
- программисты около 30 фокусируют знания (низкое кол-во меток), к 40-50 их кругозор возрастает, результаты для 60-летних неоднозначны
- не обнаружено статически значимой разницы между репутацией более и менее юных программистов в метках новых технологий таких как clojure, django, git, jquery, linq, mongodb, ruby-on-rails, silverlight

Comment: Интересное исследование

Answer (score 0):

"Стать лидом", основать свою компанию - кому как. Лично я это избегал всеми способами, потому что не моё. Хотя и пробовал. 
Вообще какое-то дурацкое (даже детское) мнение, что раз программист, то Билл Гейтс или Балмер :) Хочется стать управленцем - идите на управленческий, учитесь там... Только учитесь, а не выбирайте IDE, не освоив написание простейшего калькулятора.

P.S. мне 43, начинал с gw-basic, tasm и турбосей. Освоение новых технологий? При хорошей базе это несложно. Ну и не забываем про "знал куда ударить" (впрочем, и тут бывают открытия даже в таком возрасте)

Comment: Ну так я о чём, это вещи "глубоко перпендикулярные".

Comment: @alexlz, надо только иметь в виду, что этот бэйсик умещался в 4KB. 

IMHO это однозначно говорит об уровне.

Comment: @avp, а у них и выбора не было, либо уместить, либо нет. Не то что нынешние условия, с бегамайтами и видеокурсами :)

P.S Помнится, мой аналог Turbo Vision в "почти" конечной редакции занимал 12 Kb, но столько было недоделано...

Comment: @avp "однозначно говорит об уровне"? Что именно говорит? Бейсики сильно разные бывают. Про современный VB в 4Kb никто не говорит. А простой классический васик -- это несколько иное.

@klopp "нынешние условия" в применении, скажем, к микроконтроллерами с 2K флеша/128b RAM тоже могут быть интересными.

Comment: @alexlz, говорит, что интеллектуальный уровень писателя и знания системы команд 8080 очень высокие.

Любой алгоритмический язык (пусть и сильно синтаксически урезанный) вместе с редактором строки и наверняка кое-какой диагностикой уложить в такой объем сложно, даже если не гнаться за скоростью интерпретации.

Comment: @avp не знаю. Не видел. Но думаю, что и язык был примитивным, и редактирование -- минимальным. То, что БГ -- человек умный, не отрицает никто. Но записывать этот продукт в шедевры программистского искусства я бы не стал. Васиков для I8080A было немало. А так -- всё бывает.

Из шедевров кодирования я слыхал в своё время про библиотеку ИС-2 для ЭВМ М-20 http://computermiracle.net/m20.html . Утверждали, что она была написана так, что улучшению уже не поддавалась, т.е. нарушалось основное правило программирования -- любую программу можно улучшить без ущерба для функциональности.

Comment: @alexlz, здорово.

Интересно, а другое известное правило -- "в любой нетривиальной программе есть хотя бы одна ошибка" эта библиотека тоже нарушала?

Comment: Ребят, не ссорьтесь :) Мне, например, понравились два тезиса.


1) "В 50 лет не солидно быть рядовым программистом, надо быть минимум Тим Лидом"



2) "48 лет - это не для программистов. А для сильно пьющих людей без специальности"


Поспорил бы, да какие наши годы. Тем более сильно пьющие :)

Comment: @avp Изначально -- наверняка нет. Но к концу 70х -- скорее да. Текст её приводился в книге Ляшенко "Программирование для машин типа М-20". google подсказал: http://code.google.com/p/m20/wiki/Documentation , http://m20.googlecode.com/svn/doc/M-220-interpreting-system.pdf
      
 А кстати, Кнут премию за нахождение ошибки в TeX'е не отменил?

Comment: Опять лимит. Правлю этот (и конец).
@klopp, а кто здесь ссорится? Это просто дружеский треп.

    ну смайлик "ирония" же :)

теперь разглядел.

--

По поводу исследований.

На главной странице есть кнопка "ИССЛЕДОВАНИЯ". А дальше, там кнопка "ПУБЛИКОВАТЬ" и набираете текст, как при задании вопроса.

--

@alexlz, а я и не слышал про такую премию.

Comment: @avp, ну смайлик "ирония" же :)

(личное: а как исследование замутить? давно не был, а тут хрен поймёшь что и как)

Comment: @avp проблема в том, что про эту премию я читал в форумах. На сайт Кнута лень было заходить. Где-то в конце 90х-начале 2000х эта( тема часто всплывала. Сейчас информации о ней не нашёл. 256-центовые премии за ошибки и опечатки в книгах и программах -- это несколько иное.

Answer (score 0):

А я вот кодю кодю.... посмотрю на свою дочь, на ее нейро само развитие.... и руки опускаются.....